# Encoding Erlang Tuple as JSON

Tags: json, erlang

How do I convert a list with Tuples & Atoms & Binary strings in a list into JSON?
I see [Erlang : Tuple List into JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923400/erlang-tuple-list-into-json)
and I found https://github.com/rustyio/BERT-JS

I want an API I can call like

`erlang_json:convert([{a, b, {{c, d}}, 1}, {"a", "b", {{cat, dog}}, 2}`

where the atoms would be converted to strings or some other standard way to process on the Javascript side.

I have complicated Erlang lists I need to send to my webpage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's unclear what `[{a, b, {{c, d}}, 1}, {"a", "b", {{cat, dog}}, 2}...` would turn into as JSON, but you might take a look at [jiffy](https://github.com/davisp/jiffy) or [jsx](https://github.com/talentdeficit/jsx). Both of them work on simple key/value structures. For instance:

```
> Term = #{a => b, c => 1, <<"x">> => <<"y">>}.
#{a => b,c => 1,<<"x">> => <<"y">>}

> jiffy:encode(Term).
<<"{\"x\":\"y\",\"c\":1,\"a\":\"b\"}">>

> jsx:encode(Term).
<<"{\"a\":\"b\",\"c\":1,\"x\":\"y\"}">>
```

If you can say what JSON you want your example input to turn into, I might be able to give you a better suggestion.

Comment: To add to this answer see https://github.com/davisp/jiffy#data-format to see the valid erlang datatypes that can give proper json.

Comment: Thanks -- I was hoping for each atom to turn into a string, as I don't think there's a way in JSON to send characters that aren't in strings. Your example code looks right so I will accept this, I will check into jiffy & jsx thank you!

Comment: But still, [JSON](http://www.json.org/) is made up of key/value pairs. If you turn the atoms to strings, you still end up with something like `{"a", "b", {{"c", "d"}}, 1}` in erlang. What key/value pairs would you want pulled out of there?

Comment: @RyanStewart yes, I understand. I was hoping to not have to write a custom JSON encoder for tuples eg. something that would convert tuples to arrays recursively and let the client side sort it out.

Answer (score 3):

Just for you
https://github.com/romanr321/t2j

You don't need to wrap it in a list though, it takes one tuple argument and returnes a json formated string.

```
>Tuple = {{key, value}, { key2, {key3, [value1, 2,3]}}}.
>t2j:t2jp(Tuple).
{"key":"value", "key2, {"key3":["value1", 2,3]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

The library `jsone` is pretty good. It can translate between maps or tuples:
https://github.com/sile/jsone

I've used it extensively and it's lightning fast.

The only problem I've found is that a map that contains a list of maps throws an error. I hope this is fixed, but maybe I'm the only tart trying to do that.